# Implemented Push() on a Stack using dynamic array

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
    void** array;
    int top;
    int capacity;
} ArrayStack;
```

and the Push() function as below:

```
void push(ArrayStack* P, void* data){
    P->top++;
    if(P->top <= P->capacity){
        P->capacity++;
        P->array = realloc( P->array, (P->capacity) * sizeof(void*) );
    }

    P->array[P->top] = data;
}
```

However it is failing while trying to assign the data to the array, what could be problem? What am I doing wrong here ?

Below is the code i'm using to test the function createStack():

```
ArrayStack* createStack(){
    ArrayStack* ret = (ArrayStack*) malloc(sizeof(ArrayStack));
    ret->top = -1;
    ret->capacity = 0;
    return ret;
}
  int main(){
        ArrayStack* testStack = createStack();
        int* ins = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *ins = 123;
        push(testStack, ins);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: `if(P->top >= P->capacity)` looks better

Comment: You never initialized `array`; set it to `NULL` in `createStack`.

Comment: The usual comment on `malloc`: don't cast the return value, as it may for example hide a forgotten `#include <stdlib.h>`. Even simpler, use `ArrayStack *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);` and you don't have to replace 2 or 3 occurrences if you ever replace `ArrayStack` by something else (additionally: `sizeof` is not a function but an operator). Ditto `int *ins = malloc(sizeof *ins);`. NB: usually, the `*` operator sits next to the variable name, not the type, when declaring pointers.

Comment: @Evert: Last point is a disputed matter of style, note.

Comment: @Ryan yes (hence "usually"). But I think that goes for use of parentheses with `sizeof` as well. I'm going from what I've found most common in my experience.

Comment: May I suggest that you should be setting capacity to a bigger number let's say 10, else you will be mostly performing reallocation. Increasing the capacity by 1 before every reallocation won't fetch you any benefits in terms of runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P->array = realloc( P->array, (P->capacity) * sizeof(void*) );`

When this line is called `p->array` shall be an allocated memory or a `NULL` value (if `NULL` returns new memory). Initialization of `p->array` is not seen.